# IN function equivalent in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

what is the equivalent of `col1 in ('a','b','c')` in pyspark?

I have tried the below, which doesn't seem to work

```
col1.isin.(['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyspark already has the isin function inbuilt [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html)

## Typical Filter Usage -

```
sparkDF.filter(F.col('dummy_col').isin([1, 2, 3]))
```

## Conditional Usage Example -

This utilises `when` function within Pyspark , other examples can be found - [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/)

```
sparkDF.withColumn('d'
        ,F.when(
                F.col('dummy_col').isin([1, 2, 3])
                ,F.concat(F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"))
          ).otherwise(F.concat(F.col("e"), F.col("f")))
        )
```

Comment: I do not want to filter the records, the formula is :  if col1 in (a,b,c) then do d = a+b+c else d=e+f

Comment: df1= df.withColumn('Test', when((col("Flag") != "Y") &(col("RT") == "10") &  
(col("AH") == 7) & (col("ID").isin(['fen','dem','HIG']), 1.05)))..This is my code..I get TypeError: Column is not iterable error...all columns areof string type...how can I fix this

Comment: You have syntactical errors , always try to spread out your statements to check for properly parenthesis closures

```
df.withColumn('Test', when(
                              (col("Flag") != "Y") & (col("RT") == "10") 
                            & (col("AH") == 7) & (col("ID").isin(['fen','dem','HIG']))
          , 1.05)
        )

```